# Need Help With Finding SEO Company/Individual

Tags: seo, search-engines, marketing, sem

I am fairly new to SEO and I have done all of the tactics and operations that I know to do to help my site rank to the number 1 spot on Google. I know that no one can guarantee the number 1 spot on Google or on any other search engine but I cannot even seem to get my website to the first page of Google's search results.

My company is looking to hire a company or individual to work on our SEO. Does anyone here know of an SEO company or individual that has had good results in the past with getting a website to the front of Google, and preferably to the number 1 spot on Google? We are willing to pay a large sum of money for our keywords to rank on the front of Google search results. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks 
John

Comment: What keywords are you hoping to rank well for? What is your site about?

Comment: "Does anyone here know of an SEO company or individual that has had good results ..." - This question is inviting highly subjective responses (and spam). Suggested rephrasing: "How can I find a professional SEO provider with experience getting first-page results?"

Comment: This question is subjective, there is no one correct answer, it's like an AD, it should be closed or made community wilki.

Comment: Made CW. Answers should follow guidelines here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: This question is being closed since it's highly opinion-based and is attracting self-promotional answers.

Answer (score 3):

I am an SEO Professional and highly recommend you learn a fair share of SEO yourself before you hire anyone. A lot depends on the keywords you are going for and their level of competition. What you are asking leaves you open to being misled.

A lot of these companies advertising first page results may get you first page results in the long tail that likely get little to no actual searches. What you likely need is a strategy that uses achievable long tail phrases to generate traffic while you work on a strategy to go for better keywords/phrases.

It is very easy to twist analytical data to show results that don't really exist. I have heard some horror stories in this area where companies throw away tens of thousands of dollars on campaigns that were never actually meant to get actual results. That is why I recommend googling seo-moz and skimming through the beginners guides. I think its still free.

I know this may not be the exact answer you were looking for but I thought it should be said.